# Is there a built-in MATLAB function to parse a variety of boolean inputs?

Tags: matlab

I need to parse various types of boolean inputs and I'm thinking about writing a very simple function to interpret any of the following as boolean TRUE (*1* in MATLAB):

```
1
true
'1'
'true'
'on'
'y'
'yes'
'enable'
'enabled'
```

I know the first two are already interpreted as 1 in MATLAB.  But is there already a function which also interprets some or all of the others as *1*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roll your own to check those strings!

```
istruestr = @(x) any(strcmpi({'1' 'true' 'on' 'y' 'yes' 'enable' 'enabled'},x));
```

Note that according to the [`strcmpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) documentation,

> The `strcmpi` function is intended for comparison of character data. When used to compare numeric data, it returns logical 0.

Comment: Thanks; that's even simpler than the one I was going to write.  So I take it there definitely is not a similar function built-in?

Comment: Not that I know of.. MATLAB can't know how you want to use arbitrary strings.